# design pattern to implement multi queue pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

Need help in designing solution to support below schenario

I am trying to implement a spring boot app that can support RabbitMQ Azure Service BUS and Amazon MQ in a single app. But at a time only one queue will be in effect (one of the 3) based on property that we are going to set from property file

```
  messaging.queue.type: rabbitmq #azure  or rabbitmq or aws
```

Since its a conditional messaging queue I have also added a @conditionalBean on my config class

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "messaging.queue.type", havingValue = "rabbitmq")
public class RabbitMQConfig {
  @Autowired
  QueueProperties properties;

  @Bean
  CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return CommonRabbitMQConfig.connectionFactory(
        properties.getHost(),
        properties.getPort(),
        properties.getUsername(),
        properties.getPassword(),
        Boolean.valueOf(properties.getIsSsl()));
  }
```

But I am also having QueueHandler Class in my current project

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMQHandler {

  @Autowired RabbitMQConsumer consumer;

  @RabbitListener(
      queues = "${spring.rabbitmq.producers[0].queues[0].name}",
      containerFactory = "publicRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
  public void handle(Message message, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) {
    try {
      channel.basicAck(tag, true);
      validateInbound(message);
    } catch (BadInboundRequestException | IOException e) {
      log. Warn("Inbound message has bad header :: {}", e.getMessage());
      return;
    }
    if (Arrays.asList(properties.getQueue().getInbound().getEvents())
        .contains(message.getHeaders().get(EVENT_HEADER_KEY))) consumer. Consume(message);
    else log. Warn("Inbound message ignored :: {}", IGNORE_MESSAGE);
  }
```

since I have added  `@RabbitListener` which refers to the config class's bean my app is failing to start.

How can I manage this all and also support other 2 services and add flag that can ON or OFF certain messaging queue?

or do we need to add @conditional annotation on Handeler class also ?

I can use the factory method but I am more looking from configuration perspection and how to isolate complete queue code of aws /rabbitmq and azure bus so that I should not have bean dependency exception in app.

regards
Dnyaneshwar Muley